# getting row names in series instead of indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm working with the dataframe containing 3 columns: country and two indicators. I am performing some calculations on these two indicators and I get the result as 'Series' - outcomes for all of the countries on the right and index on the left. Is it possible to replace indexes with the respective countries names?
here is the operation:

```
pow(df.mean(axis=1)-min(df.mean(axis=1)),2)
```

[image]

Comment: `df['newcol] = pow(df.mean(axis=1)-min(df.mean(axis=1)),2)` , and then print `df` maybe

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code

```
pow(df.mean(axis=1)-min(df.mean(axis=1)),2).rename(index={1:"aa", 2:"bb"})
```